# How many apprequest can i send at a time

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook.web.swc and i am sending the apprequest to 100 persons at a time but an error is thrown by the facebook. Can anyone tell me that how many apprequests can be send a time.

Comment: Not a programming question (more a Facebook policy question.)

Comment: What error is thrown? does it perhaps tell you what the upper limit is?

Answer (score 2):

There's no limit policy-wise or technically to the number of [requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) which can be sent per user per day.

However, the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) can send only **50** requests in a single call